# Combining two parts of Dataframes: "ValueError: array length 1 does not match index length 586"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to built a new dataframe out of some previous dataframes that I got from a CSV and did some calculations on with something like

```
addtest = pd.DataFrame({'coordinates': 123456,
                        'level1': RainD.level,
                        'coordinates1': 789,
                        'level2':RainD2.level})
```

In the above example, `level1` and `level2` are just imported levels from a CSV, without anything applied to them, and I get a new dataframe without issues, even though the levels from the 2 different CSV files have differing start and end dates (which is intentional).

**However if I try "the same" in my full script, it errors with**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "standardization_loop.py", line 365, in <module>
    'SGW_month':Yearlist_sorted.level})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 383, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 515, in _init_dict
    dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5263, in _arrays_to_mgr
     index = extract_index(arrays)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5325, in extract_index
     raise ValueError(msg)
 ValueError: array length 1 does not match index length 586
```

**What does this error want to tell me?**

What did I do to get there:

```
Combined_df = pd.DataFrame({'Coordinates':Coordinates,
              'SGW_year':RainD_SGW.level,
              'SGW_month':Yearlist_sorted.level})
```

**Edit(See comments too):** The Coordinates are just numbers, however if I remove that part, I still get an error, though that now changed to an `AssertionError: Block shape incompatible with manager`. Or did I overlook that type the first time? But still, according to the tests below, the two dataframe levels should fit:

And to make sure that they are indeed matching and dont have duplicates, I also looked at `RainD_SGW.level` and `Yearlist_sorted.level` before:

```
Yearlist_sorted.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 586 entries, 1965-12-01 00:00:00 to 2014-09-01 00:00:00
Data columns:
level    586  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)None
Yearlist_sorted.index.get_duplicates()
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
Length: 0, Freq: None, Timezone: None
RainD_SGW.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 586 entries, 1965-12-01 00:00:00 to 2014-09-01 00:00:00
Data columns:
level    586  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1)None
RainD_SGW.index.get_duplicates()
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
Length: 0, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Looks good to me? They do seem to be of the same size, in the same date range, and they are not suffering from duplicates. So what else is it?

Comment: Can you give us some information on the `Coordinates` variable? It appears that it could be a scalar, instead of a array_like structure of length `586`.

Comment: The `Coordinates` are just a number (yet), as in my ipython trials. Also, If I remove that line, and just do `Combined_df = pd.DataFrame({      'SGW_year':RainD_SGW.level,
              'SGW_month':Yearlist_sorted.level})` I still get the same error.

Comment: Cant edit the previous comment: Its not the same error, its now an `Assertion error`. I have edited it into the question.

Comment: That's weird. If I am not mistaken, this error means that one of the elements in the constructor of `DataFrame` is not an array or Series, but some multidimensional thingy like a 2d numpy array or a data frame. Are you using the latest version of pandas?

Comment: I'm on 0.10, the version fedora ships as stable. It is all but that, however such basic things shouldn'T be buggy anymore?!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug, it can be, it doesn't have to be. Your question does not provide runnable code, so we can just guess.. Note that pandas `10.x` was released at the end of 2012, so I guess updating is probably not the worst idea  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I can count this as an answer, but I found a workaround (which in turn, gives me even more, different questions, mainly if I actually know what the hell I am doing…)

Anyways, here it goes:

```
RainD['SGW_month'] = Yearlist_sorted
RainD['SGW_year'] = RainD_SGW
RainD['Coordinates'] = str(Coordinates)
```

So instead of trying to build a new Dataframe, and specifying what parts of my calculated Dataframes I want, I just add it all to my original Dataframe (the `RainD`), and it seems like it is intelligent enough to just use the levels from those DAtaframes.

But it doesnt seem right to me. I am afraid this will fail, if i have Dataframes with more than just one thing besides their index in it.

Also, I told the value `Coordinates` to be a string. I thought they already were one, but seems like I was wrong.